# eureka client in Finchley.M9 does not work properly?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

due to 2.1.4.RELEASE of spring-kafka requires springboot 2.0, I had to upgrade my spring cloud to Finchley.M9. However, after the upgrade, I can no longer find the "DiscoveryClient" logs. I look for "DiscoveryClient" log since the application is not registered to eureka server (running Dalston.SR5 release). So my questions is: (1) does Finchley.M9's eureka client compatible to Dalston.SR5 eureka server? (2) how can I check that Finchley.M9's eureka client is working properly?

Thank you.

Comment: We will only maintain compatibility between one version back, so you would have to use Edgware.SR3 in your Eureka server.  If that is not working than please open an issue with an example project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: it should, you need to change your artifacts, as they have migrated in Edgware https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Edgware-Release-Notes

Comment: @RyanBaxter & spencergibb: It turns out I miss typed few characters for the dependency jar file, I apologize for the hassle.